# How do I run script with admin perm?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

im trying coding metin2 bot but it dont work. Because that python script not working with admin permissions. How do i run script with admin perm?

I just tried some code blocks. First one:

```
import admin

if not admin.isUserAdmin():
    admin.runAsAdmin()
else: 
    print("I am not root :(")
```

But it dont work. It gave me an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\...\Desktop\...\testmetin.py", line 3, in <module>
    if not admin.isUserAdmin():
AttributeError: module 'admin' has no attribute 'isUserAdmin'
```

Second one:

```
import os
import sys
import win32com.shell.shell as shell
ASADMIN = 'asadmin'

if sys.argv[-1] != ASADMIN:
    script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
    params = ' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [ASADMIN])
    shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile=sys.executable, lpParameters=params)
    sys.exit(0)
    print ("I am root now.")
```

Again its gave me an error like this:
"Import "win32com.shell.shell" could not be resolved"

It is keep continue like this. Please help me guys. I spent 2 days for this.

Comment: Just checking, this is for windows right?

Comment: Yes, thats' right.

Comment: Bonus question, how is the program being launched, by a person double clicking, command line, or a scheduled task?

Comment: I'm just running on terminal.

Comment: Might have a work around, if you launch `cmd` as an admin it will run with admin privileges.  If I need my python to run with specific rights, I don't do it in code, I usually just have it as a scheduled task that runs as a specific user.

Comment: It gave me an error: C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Users\\....\\Desktop\\cw'

Comment: "I usually just have it as a scheduled task that runs as a specific user." How do you doing that?

Comment: `IF (NOT root) -> runAsAdmin() ELSE -> "I'm not root"` that logic is wrong

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez what is the right logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows:

Start->Task Scheduler

Action->Create Task

Run whether user is logged on or not

Change User or Group

And then under `Actions` point it to your program.  This will launch the job as your user you have picked, with those permissions.

[image]

Note, under `Actions` after you point to your program, you *may* have to fill the `Start in` section.  For me if my program live here:

`d:\git\code\python\test.py`

I have to put:

`d:\git\code\python`

in the `Start in`

Comment: Where is the Start in section? Im using other lang.

Comment: On the `Actions` tab in the image.

Comment: Yeah, i already did it. Now i will try run the script.

Comment: It didnt work bro.  It is still giving error: "can't find 'main' module in 'C:\\Users\\....\\Desktop\\cw"

Comment: if you do `pip check admin` do you have the module installed?

Comment: It said: "No broken requirements found." but i installed it.

Comment: cmd> pip install admin
Requirement already satisfied: admin in c:\users\....\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages

Comment: I solved it bro. Thanks so much. It's about filename :/. I run terminal with administrator and run py scripts. its working. This solution not necessary but i will accept it. Thank you again.

Comment: happy to help :) glad we got it going